# Sylius old composer update

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have used sylius as e-commerce platform and working on it by creating my own website.

After 4 months of job I want to extend my system with one more bundle using composer.json.
But there is problem when I want to update composer via json, sylius bundles makes problem like there is changes in sylius bundles, I can't update anymore old sylius composer, seems like my work in last 4 months by using sylius is gone?

Can anybody help is there any solution to continue my work with old sylius's `composer.json`?

There is problem with inventory bundle that was 0.1.* now is that version removed and there is 1.0 version which is not satisfailable for the rest of my bundles as omnipay , flow bundle etc... and when I resolve one of them that goes in next couple like there is no solution?

Error:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package sylius/installer-bundle 0.1.* could not be found.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package sylius/omnipay-bundle 0.9.*@dev could not be found.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for sylius/flow-bundle 0.1.* -> satisfiable by sylius/flow-bundle[v0.1.0].
    - sylius/flow-bundle v0.1.0 requires sylius/installer-bundle 0.1.* -> no matching package found.


    "php":                                  ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony":                      ">=2.2,<2.3-dev",
    "doctrine/orm":                         ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle":             "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle":    "*",
    "twig/extensions":                      "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle":               "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle":           "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle":               "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle":           "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "mathiasverraes/money":                 "dev-master@dev",
    "jms/translation-bundle":               "1.1.*",
    "sylius/installer-bundle":              "0.1.*",
    "sylius/assortment-bundle":             "0.1.*",
    "sylius/cart-bundle":                   "0.3.*",
    "sylius/money-bundle":                  "0.1.*",
    "sylius/taxation-bundle":               "0.1.*",
    "sylius/shipping-bundle":               "0.1.*",
    "sylius/addressing-bundle":             "0.1.*",
    "sylius/sales-bundle":                  "0.1.*",
    "sylius/promotions-bundle":             "0.1.*",
    "sylius/inventory-bundle":              "0.1.*",
    "sylius/taxonomies-bundle":             "0.1.*",
    "sylius/settings-bundle":               "0.1.*",
    "sylius/payments-bundle":               "0.1.*",
    "sylius/flow-bundle":                   "0.1.*",
    "sylius/resource-bundle":               "0.1.*",
    "sylius/omnipay-bundle":                "0.9.*@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle":                "0.11.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle":         "1.3.1",
    "fsc/hateoas-bundle":                   "0.3.x-dev",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle":         "0.2.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker":                     "1.1.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":              "2.0.*",
    "liip/imagine-bundle":                  "0.9.*",
    "athari/yalinqo":                       "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
    "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php": "dev-master",
    "mandrill/mandrill":                     "1.0.*"
```

Comment: Please post your composer.json.

Comment: I have add require from my composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should require "1.0.*" or "1.0.*@dev" depending on your minimum-stability setting. You can also lock on specific tags.